# Get some data from nested object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this nested object (json):

```
const json = {
  "application": {
    "App1": {
      "cats": [
        1
      ]
    },
    "App2": {
      "cats": [
        3
      ]
    },
    "App3": {
      "cats": [
        1,
        2
      ]
    }
  },
  "categories": {
    "1": {
      "name": "FirstCategory"
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "SecondCategory"
    },
    "3": {
      "name": "ThirdCategory"
    }
  }
};
```

This object has two main properties: `application` and `categories`.

I want to map over `application`'s `cats` array and get `name` property of each element of `cats` array.

So the final result should look like:

```
{
   "App1": "FirstCategory",
   "App2": "ThirdCategory",
   "App3": "FirstCategory, ThirdCategory"
}
```

I have tried to use `map` function, but the main difficulty is that inside `applicaiton` property `cats` is array (can have multiple values). So the code below didn't work:

```
Object.values(json.application).map(val => {
    Object.keys(json.categories).map(key => {
       //print something
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for an elegant solution.

```js
const json = {
  "application": {
    "App1": {
      "cats": [
        1
      ]
    },
    "App2": {
      "cats": [
        3
      ]
    },
    "App3": {
      "cats": [
        1,
        2
      ]
    }
  },
  "categories": {
    "1": {
      "name": "FirstCategory"
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "SecondCategory"
    },
    "3": {
      "name": "ThirdCategory"
    }
  }
};

//Getting Application object
const application = json.application

//Getting Categories object
const categories = json.categories

//initializing reduce with a blank object and pushing all the keys of the application object
//Looping over keys of application object
const requiredOutput = Object.keys(application).reduce((out, appKey) => {
    //Setting value based on categories name
    out[appKey] = application[appKey].cats.map(id => categories[id].name)
    return out
}, {})

console.log(requiredOutput)
```

PS: You can refer [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ashish-r/91ee6ad307687061b765dcf32de40589) for safe reading from a nested object.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with this.

```
    for(let val in json.application){
      json.application[val] = json.application[val].cats.map(cat => json.categories[cat].name).join(",")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const result = Object.keys(json.application).reduce((a,key) => {
    a[key] = json.application[key].cats
        .map(cat => json.categories[cat].name)
        .join(", ")
    return a;
}, {})
```

1. loop over keys of application
2. for each key loop over car, and for each cat return string value from category
3. join list of cat strings